# Trying to run falcon-40b model locally. need help the model is not giving any output and is showing exit code 1 on VS Code

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, large-language-model

I have Nvidia rtx 3060 and decided to give it a try for my own project. So i have downloaded all the model files into a folder ./Model, parallel to app.py. I just wanted to test the llm before i proceed further. But when i try to execute the code it doesnt produce any output and also when i hover over the executed command on VScode it says `Command Executed now and failed (Exit Code 1)`.

Here is the testing code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

# Set the path to your model directory
model_directory = "./model"

# Initialize the tokenizer and model from the specified directory
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_directory)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_directory)

# Ensure the model is using the GPU
model = model.to("cuda")

# Define the prompt
prompt = """
<human>: explain llms like i am five
<assistant>:
"""

# Configuration for the generation
generation_config = {
    "max_length": 200,  # Adjust the maximum length of the generated tokens
    "temperature": 0.7,  # Temperature controls the randomness
    "top_p": 0.7,        # top_p controls the nucleus sampling
    "num_return_sequences": 1,  # Number of sequences to generate
    "pad_token_id": tokenizer.eos_token_id,  # Padding token
    "eos_token_id": tokenizer.eos_token_id,  # End of sequence token
}

# Encode the prompt
encoding = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")

# Generate a response using the encoded prompt and generation configuration
with torch.no_grad():  # Disables gradient calculation to save memory and speeds up computation
    outputs = model.generate(
        input_ids=encoding["input_ids"], 
        attention_mask=encoding["attention_mask"], 
        **generation_config
    )

# Decode the generated tokens to text
generated_text = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

# Print the generated text
print(generated_text)
```

Here are the VScode screen shots:
[VScode showing Exit Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxX0A.png)

What am I doing wrong and how to resolve this?

I tried to execute the above given code. I should have got a text response but i got nothing.